# Creating corpora for a tribal language POS tagging

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am using NLTK to extract nouns from a text-string and each of its word  already have POS tags in them in (ibaloi) language which be later used on creating grammar:

```
sentence = "this is a tribal language"
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
taggedWords = tagged_text = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.Text(words))
```

There is no problem in english. **Is there a way to make it work in tribal(ibaloi) language as well?**

(I am new to natural language process taking some tutorials which is great by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28153/how-to-tag-pos-in-nltk-for-a-language-that-is-not-english) similar question where the OP also had a wordlist containing word and part of speech (noun, verb, etc.) in an Excel file, for a language not in NLTK.